2000 Peugeot 206 can't make it up steep hills
long term reader first time asker.
Wondering if I could pick the brains of those with far more car knowledge than myself. My situation is this: I drive a 2000 Peugeot 206 with around 140k miles on it. The car hasn't been serviced for a couple of years as I've only been doing about 1,000 miles a year for the last five years (I know!).
In the last few weeks, the car has struggled to get up hills and been sluggish pulling away. When I say struggle, I had a bail on a 8 degree hill a few days back. I was doing 50 odd when I got to the hill, a couple of hundred metres later I was down to 40, then 30.  Thankfully, there was a side road so I was able to leave the hill as I was down to around 25mph (it's a 50 road).  Then again a couple of days ago, on a less steep hill I was doing 50 when approaching the hill and by the time I got to the top (would say half a mile to a mile), I was down to 20mph. Another half a mile and I wouldn't have made it. This is becoming a little dangerous!
Changing gear in either situation didn't seem to help as when I pressed harder on the accelerator, the revs increased to 5k but the car didn't seem to get any faster.
On flat roads and small hills, it seems fine. That being said, if I have to pull onto a road at pace it can be a bit slow to get up to speed. However, once up to speed, no issues.
For the first time yesterday, I did notice a rattling noise from the exhaust but that sounded like a loose fitting bolt but could be wrong.
The MOT is in a couple of weeks. It has a couple of other minor issues such as reverse bulb gone. Happy to pay a couple of hundred to get it through the MOT on the minor faults but the loss of power is sounding very expensive.
Would anyone have a rough clue as to what the cause could be, please? If it is anything major, ill cancel the MOT and look for a new car instead.
Thank you

If the revs increase when you press the accelerator, without going any faster, you could have a slipping clutch.

@WeatherVane thank you very much for the reply. The car is fine on normal flat roads and modest hills. Would this still be the case if it were a slipping clutch?  Thank you

Is this a manual or automatic?

It certainly can be the case: the clutch only slipping when excessive load is placed on it. And if it's a manual gearbox, and the revs increase without an increase in road speed, the clutch must be slipping (unless the driven wheels are spinning, which you would be more aware of).

If the clutch is slipping going up hills you'd start to smell it.

Yes, the car is a manual gearbox

You need codes. There's so many things it could be, you need to narrow the field. Please edit with more information: if you floor it on level ground do revs increase without an increase in speed? In neutral can you get maximum revs? Does the engine run rough at any point? Is fuel consumption normal? Get a cheap OBD bluetooth reader and Torque and get some more data.

@GdD thank you. 'if you floor it on level ground do revs increase without an increase in speed' on a very steep hill, yes. Ill look into getting one of those. I think given the age of the car and the pending MOT, it might not be worth fixing it. Thanks for your assistance

You never know. It could be something dead simple like a fuel filter restricting fuel flow, which you could replace yourself for 10 quid.
